# How can I resize a widget on an android application by using AppWidgetHostView?

Tags: android, android-appwidget, android-appwidget-list

I created an application that has a widget. I would like to resize the widget but it does not work.
The widget size does not change between w/ and w/o *widgetView.updateAppWidgetSize(options, 100, 100, 200, 200)*. Why does updateAppWidgetSize not work? How can I change the widget size?

MainActivity:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var appWidgetManager: AppWidgetManager
    private lateinit var appWidegetHost: AppWidgetHost

    private val REQUEST_BIND_APPWIDGET = 1

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(this)
        appWidegetHost = AppWidgetHost(this, 12345).apply {
            startListening()
        }

        val appWidgetId = appWidegetHost.allocateAppWidgetId()
        val appWidgetInfo = appWidgetManager.installedProviders.get(5)

        if (appWidgetManager.bindAppWidgetIdIfAllowed(appWidgetId, appWidgetInfo.provider)) {
            addAppWidget(appWidgetId, appWidgetInfo)
        } else {
            val intent = Intent(AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_BIND)
            intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetId);
            intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_PROVIDER, appWidgetInfo.provider);
            startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_BIND_APPWIDGET)
        }
    }

    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == REQUEST_BIND_APPWIDGET) {
                val appWidgetId = data!!.getIntExtra(
                    AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID,
                    AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID
                )
                if (appWidgetId != AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID) {
                    val appWidgetInfo = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetInfo(appWidgetId)
                    addAppWidget(appWidgetId, appWidgetInfo)
                }
            }
        } else { }
    }

    override fun onStop() {
        super.onStop()
        appWidegetHost.stopListening()
    }

    private fun addAppWidget(appWidgetId: Int, appWidgetInfo: AppWidgetProviderInfo) {
        val widgetView = appWidegetHost.createView(this, appWidgetId, appWidgetInfo)
        val options = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetOptions(appWidgetId)
        widgetView.updateAppWidgetSize(options, 100, 100, 200, 200)
        widgetView.setAppWidget(appWidgetId, appWidgetInfo)
        widgets.addView(widgetView)
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/black"
        tools:context=".MainActivity" android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"     
                android:id="@+id/widgets">
        </LinearLayout>

 </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `updateAppWidgetSize()` method only affects the min and max dimensions, not the current dimension.

To change the widget size, do it how you would any other View, by modifying the LayoutParams:

```
widgetView.layoutParams = widgetView.layoutParams.apply {
    width = /* your width */
    height = /* your height */
}
```

Comment: @kenjn04; It happens to you too, that when you insert the widget takes up all the space both in height and width?
How did you solve it?
What size do you take?
I tried like this:
ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = widgetLayout.getLayoutParams ();
             lp.height = newAppWidgetProviderInfo.minHeight;
             lp.width = newAppWidgetProviderInfo.minWidth;
             hostView.requestLayout ();
But it does not seem to work properly.

Comment: @Paul: Currently I am doing like this.The cellX and cellY are calculated based on "Determining a size for your widget" on https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/widget_design
        val cellX = ((appWidgetInfo.minWidth / density + 30) / 70).toInt()
        val cellY = ((appWidgetInfo.minHeight / density + 30) / 70).toInt()
        val width= (cellX * CELL_SIZE_PX * density).toInt()
        val height = (cellY * CELL_SIZE_PX * density).toInt()
        hostView.layoutParams = ViewGroup.LayoutParams(width, height)
        hostView.requestLayout()